# IF statement get triggered anyway

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have an exercise and I'm not getting why it ain't working.

If the string contains only "!", it still triggers the first if statement.

```
Function Get-BobResponse() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$HeyBob
    )

    if(($HeyBob -match "!") -and ($HeyBob -like "*?*")){
        return "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!"
    }

    if($HeyBob -match "!"){
        return "Whoa, chill out!"
    }

    if($HeyBob -Like "*?*"){
        return "Sure"
    }

    if($HeyBob -eq ""){
        return "Fine. Be that way!"
    }
    else{
        return "Whatever"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't help but think a switch statement would be better :)

Comment: The exercise is meant to be about if-else, so id better use them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wildcard pattern:

```
*?*
```

will match *any string* with *at least one character* - because `?` is a metacharacter meaning "exactly one of any character".

You can use `WildcardPattern.Escape()` to escape metacharacters or groups:

```
$questionMark = [WildcardPattern]::Escape('?')
$HeyBob -like "*$questionMark*"
```

In single-quoted (ie, literal) strings, you can escape it manually with a backtick (`` ` ``):

```
$HeyBob -like '*`?*'
```

Beware that you'll have to double-escape the backtick in double-quoted strings (since PowerShell uses backticks for both expandable strings *and* wildcard patterns)

```
$HeyBob - like "*``?*"
```

---

You could also have used regex in both cases, although in that case you'd still need to escape `?` (since it's a special quantifier in regex):

```
$HeyBob -match '!' -and $HeyBob -match [regex]::Escape('?')
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
$HeyBob -match "!"
```

does a regex match, and as `$HeyBob` is `!` is will evalaute to `true`.

Next:

```
$HeyBob -like "*?*"
```

Is a wildcard that says match zero or more characters (the first *), followed by one character (this matches the !) followed by zero or more characters (the second *). The matches against `!`.

As both match you end up with `$true -and $true` which is true and causes the first `if` statement to execute.